# Determining whether the given topology on $\mathbb R ^2$ is second countable

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $\mathscr{T}$ be the topology on $\mathbb R ^2$ generated by $\{ U(f,g): f,g \text{ are real valued continuous on }\mathbb R \text{ and }f<g \}$ where $U(f,g)=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb R ^2 : f(x)<y<g(x) \text{ for each }x\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Then determine whether $\mathscr T$ is second countable.

---

Here's my attempt:

My claim is that $\mathscr T$ is second countable. Consider $\mathfrak B =\{ U(p_1 , p_2) : p_1,p_2\in \mathbb Q[x]\}$. Clearly $\mathfrak B$ is countable.

Let $f,g$ be real valued continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f<g$. By Stone-Weierstrass theorem, we can find a sequence of polynomials $(f_n)$ and $(g_n)$ such that

1. $f<f_n < g_n<g$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and
2. $(f_n)\to f$ and $(g_n) \to g$.

Now, it is easy to see that $U(f,g)=\bigcup _{n\in \mathbb N} U(f_n,g_n)$.
So, $\mathscr T$ is second countable.

---

Is my claim and proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your $\mathfrak{B}$ is not a base for this topology, because the sets $U(f,g)$ are not a base for it: they are only a subbase. Here is a concrete example of an open set that is not a union of sets of the form $U(f,g)$. Let

$$\begin{align*}
f_0(x)&=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x<-1\\
-\sqrt{1-x^2},&\text{if }-1\le x\le 1\\
0,&\text{if }x>1\,,
\end{cases}\\
g_0(x)&=1\,,\\\\
f_1(x)&=-1\,,\text{ and}\\
g_1(x)&=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x<-1\\
\sqrt{1-x^2},&\text{if }-1\le x\le 1\\
0,&\text{if }x>1\,.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

Then

$$U(f_0,g_0)\cap U(f_1,g_1)=\left\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:x^2+y^2<1\right\}\,,$$

the open unit disk in the plane, which does not contain any of the sets $U(f,g)$ with $f<g$, yet as an intersection of two open sets it must itself be open. Let $\mathscr{B}$ be the family of all intersections of finitely many of the subbasic open sets $U(f,g)$; then

$$\mathscr{T}=\left\{\bigcup\mathscr{U}:\mathscr{U}\subseteq\mathscr{B}\right\}\,.$$

A more fundamental problem with your approach appears when you consider $U\left(\sin x,\frac12+\sin x\right)$: there is no polynomial $p$ such that $\sin x<p<\frac12+\sin x$. The problem is that you’re trying to apply the Weierstrass approximation theorem, which deals with functions on a closed interval, to functions on the whole real line.

The example above suggests an alternative approach. Let $\tau$ be the usual topology on $\Bbb R^2$. The example can be modified to show that $\tau\subseteq\mathscr{T}$. If you can then show that $\mathscr{T}\subseteq\tau$, you’re almost done.

Comment: Yes, right! Would my proof have worked if we consider $\mathscr{T}$ on $[0,1]\times \mathbb R$ and the subbase with $f,g$ to be real valued continuous function on $[0,1]$ instead of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @ashK: You’d still have to deal with the fact that the sets $U(f,g)$ aren’t a base for the topology, so you’d have to show that using only polynomials with rational coefficients for $f$ and $g$ would give you a countable subbase generating the same topology, but yes, I think that it should work.